# How to explode array values

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I got the array values but I don't know how to explore the values in laravel. I am a new for laravel please help me.

```
    view()->composer('admin.sidebar', function ($view) {
    $usertypeid = \Auth::user()->role; 
    $moduleRs = DB::table('users')
             ->join('permissions','users.role', '=', 'permissions.role_id')
             ->select('users.role as usersrole','permissions.role_id as role_id','permissions.module_name as module_name')
           ->where('users.role', '=', $usertypeid)
            ->get();
        $view->moduleData = $moduleRs; 
        $data=$moduleRs;
    if ( count($data) > 0 )
        { 
            $result = array();
            foreach($data as $row){
                if(!isset($result[$row->role_id])) {
                    $result[$row->role_id] = array(
                        'role_id' => $row->role_id, 
                        'module_name' => array( $row->module_name), 
                    );
                }else{
                    $result[$row->role_id]['module_name'] = array_merge($result[$row->role_id]['module_name'], array($row->module_name) ); 
                }
            }
            $result =  array_values($result);
        $view->moduleData = $result;
        }
        else 
        {
            $view->moduleData=null;
        }
         });
 }
```

Can explode value? I got the array values as correct manner.

Comment: Can you add words in your question ? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: This is for roles and permissions for particular user.I have display the array values as correct but how can i explode a array values????

Comment: What do you mean by explode ?? and what is the array values structure ??

Comment: This is my array structure.I want the module name as name not an id. array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "role_id" => "0"
    "module_id" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "0,4,5"
    ]
  ]
]

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
 $view->moduleData = $moduleRs;
```

with:

```
$view->with('moduleData', $moduleRs);
```

and put it at the end of your view composer so that your function will look like :

```
view()->composer('admin.sidebar', function ($view) {
    $moduleRs = DB::table('users')
        ->join('permissions','users.role', '=', 'permissions.role_id')
        ->select('users.role as usersrole','permissions.role_id as role_id','permissions.module_name as module_name')
        ->where('users.role', '=', \Auth::user()->role)
        ->get();

    $moduleData = null;

    if ( count($moduleRs) > 0 ) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($moduleRs as $row){
            if(!isset($result[$row->role_id])) {
                $result[$row->role_id] = [
                    'role_id' => $row->role_id,
                    'module_name' => [$row->module_name],
                ];
            }else{
                $result[$row->role_id]['module_name'] = array_merge($result[$row->role_id]['module_name'], [$row->module_name] );
            }
        }
        $result =  array_values($result);
        $moduleData = $result;
    } 

    $view->with('moduleData', $moduleData);
});
```

Comment: The code works perfectly but i dont want the module name's id.i want a name not an id.......array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "role_id" => "0"
    "module_name" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "0,4,5"
    ]
  ]
]